# Const function in Delphi

Tags: delphi, function, constants, delphi-6

In the Delphi code I am looking at I've found the following set of lines:

```
const
    function1: function(const S: String): String = SomeVariable1;
    function2: function(const S: String): String = SomeVariable2;
```

What is this doing? I mean, not the actual code within the functions, but what does it do to declare a function inside the const section and compare(?) it with a variable value?  I'm assuming the single equals is a comparison since that's what it is everywhere else in Delphi.

Thank you.

Comment: Andreas explained **what** this is. However I can't see what this is for. Do you have "Assignable typed constants" enabled in the project?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, the equals is an assignment, as this is how constants are assigned. Consider, for example,

```
const Pi = 3.1415;
```

or

```
const s = 'This is an example';
```

There are also 'typed constants':

```
const Pi: extended = 3.1415;
```

In your snippet above, we define a typed constant that holds a function of signature `function(const S: String): String`. And we assign the (compatible) function `SomeVariable1` to it.

`SomVariable1` has to be defined earlier in the code, for instance, as

```
function SomeVariable1(const S: String): String;
begin
  result := S + '!';
end;
```

Consider the following example:

```
function SomeVariable1(const S: String): String;
begin
  result := S + '!';
end;

const
  function1: function(const S: String): String = SomeVariable1;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  caption := function1('test');
end;
```

Answer (score 8):

Andreas's answer covers the technical bits very well, but I'd like to provide an answer to this part:

> What is this doing?

More along the lines of `Why use this weired-looking construct`? I can think of two reasons:

- The code is written with `{$J+}` (assignable typed constants), and the "constant" is assigned a different value at some point. If `function1` were declared as a variable, the initialization would need to be done in the `initialization` section of the unit, and that might be too late (if some other unit's `initialization` section runs before this one and attempts calling the `function1` "function")
- Used if the function name was changed from `function1` to `SomeVariable1` and there's 3rd party code that can't easily be changed. This provides a one-line way of declaring the alias.

Comment: It looks like the second bullet point is right judging from a quick search of the project without finding the function name SomeVariable1.